# map iframe not showing properly before refreshing manually the document mode

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe that displays a google map. It has always been working well but it seems like that the new update from google is causing me troubles. At least that's what I think.

There is one thing that make it work: When we do F12, change the document mode to IE7 , then go back to IE8 , the map 
displays correclty.

This is how it is displayed in localhost

[image]

And this is what it looks like on both my test and production servers

[image]

My code is :

```
<iframe width="925" height="750" src="https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=4+place+richeb%C3%A9+lille&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&sll=46.22475,2.0517&sspn=25.428258,56.90918&hnear=4+Place+Richeb%C3%A9,+59000+Lille&t=m&z=16&output=embed" frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="no">
```

We've cleared the browser cache and restarted the service corresponding to the IIS server on the remote server.

There is one thing that make it work: When we do F12, change the document mode to IE7 , then go back to IE8 , the map 
displays correclty.

Is it possible that this single iframe does not understand the code below ?

Does someone have a clue what's causing this problem?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE: the code from this page http://www.richiroutreach.com/blog/embedding-google-maps  doesn't work either on my pages.... 
But the website itself (richiroutreach) displays perfectly.

So it is a problem with my servers?

Answer (score 0):

DId you try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`
Call this on `onload` event.

Comment: Hum, I didn't mention it but I'm not using google maps APIs because I can't in my context